# Android Studio - Kill Process Restarts App?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not sure why this is happening, but when I use Android studio and click the red x to terminate my application, it will restart my application to the main activity. I noticed it only happens when I have progressed to another activity from the main activity.

For example, if I try to kill the process when I am looking at the Activity A screen, the process is killed fine with no restart but if I kill the process when I am looking at Activity B pressed from a button on Activity A it will restart the process.

Any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found, that "Terminate application" is implemented as `System.exit(1)`.

Looks like Androids' `exit(int)` function is implemented softly to save activity stack.

For my opinion, it is because "Terminate application" is needed to debug application relaunch, when device memory is low. So it is very useful in such sequence:

- Launch application, open some activities
- Hide application by pressing "Home"
- Terminate application in Android Studio
- Reopen application on device, application should restore last activity, not
  the main one

And its behaviour when application is not hidden is unexpectable. And it is so due to implementation of `exit`. It saves part of the stack, but terminates the visible activity, and relaunch application then to restore stack.

Comment: Got it, so it really doesn't terminate the entire application just that activity. I assume this is a way to test against users who put the app in the background on a specific activity for awhile and try to return later, correct?

Comment: Yes! I've just tested on 3 and 4 launched activities - it terminates only the last one. And yes again, I'm also assume, that this is the way to test return from the background. I'm using it so and read about it also.

Comment: Great! Thank you, this is something I definitely didn't know.

Comment: @JoeGinley: This answer is helpful, but I disagree with the comments that indicate the entire application is not terminated.  When I test, the logcat output clearly shows the process for the app is killed.  You can confirm this by opening the AS `logcat` window, setting filters to "No Filters" and looking at the output at the time you take the terminate action.  You will see `AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped` followed by `ActivityManager: Process com.example.yourapp (pid 29469) (adj 0) has died.`

Comment: Thank you. I've mentioned your comment into answer. I'm also noticed that application restarts.

Comment: @qbix Any reason why it is working for you? How is your AndroidManifest setup?

Comment: @JoeGinley:  Sorry--my comment wasn't clear.  I see the restart also.  I just wanted to clarify that the entire app  is being killed and restarted, not just any particular activity.  I think Artem is correct that the terminate action was probably implemented this way to help developers testing the case where the system terminates a background app due to memory pressure and the developer then wants to confirm that the app correctly restarts using saved state.